# How to read the values of IconLayouts REG_BINARY registry file

Tags: python, windows, registry, binaryfiles

I want to make a program that gets the positions of the icons on the screen. And with some research I found out that the values I needed were in a registry binary file called IconLayouts (Located in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\1\Desktop) I used python to get the positions using the winreg module. And succeeded on getting the values.

```
from winreg import *

aReg = ConnectRegistry(None, HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
aKey = OpenKey(aReg, r"Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\1\Desktop", REG_BINARY)

name, value, type_ = EnumValue(aKey, 9)
value = value.replace(b'\x00', b'')
```

This is the code I have. But the problem is I don't know what to do with these values. The program returns something like:

```
b'\x03\x01\x01\x01\x04,::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}>  ,::{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}>  \x13Timetables.jpeg>  \nfolder>\\ \x01\x02\x01\x01\x02\x01\x0c\x04\x01\x04\x80?\x01@\x020A\x03'
```

I would appreciate if you would help me decipher this output and get the positions from it.

Comment: You should have a look into [Windows Shellbag Forensics](https://web.archive.org/web/20190430193554/http://www.williballenthin.com/forensics/shellbags/). I think what you are looking for is the `ITEMPOS` structure.

Comment: The supported way to read icon positions is with IFolderView.

Comment: But is there a way to use IFolderView in python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code snippet could help. It's very, very simplified code combined from [Windows Shellbag Forensics](https://web.archive.org/web/20190430193554/http://www.williballenthin.com/forensics/shellbags/) article and [`shellbags.py` script](https://github.com/williballenthin/shellbags) (the latter is written in Python 2.7 hence unserviceable for me).

```
import struct
from winreg import *

aReg = ConnectRegistry(None, HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
aKey = OpenKey(aReg, r"Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\1\Desktop", REG_BINARY)

name, value, type_ = EnumValue(aKey, 9)

offset = 0x10

head = [struct.unpack_from("<H", value[offset:],0)[0],
        struct.unpack_from("<H", value[offset:],2)[0],
        struct.unpack_from("<H", value[offset:],4)[0],
        struct.unpack_from("<H", value[offset:],6)[0]]
number_of_items = struct.unpack_from("<I", value[offset:],8)[0] # 4 bytes (dword)
offset += 12
for x in range( number_of_items):
    uint16_size     = struct.unpack_from("<H", value[offset:],0)[0];
    uint16_flags    = struct.unpack_from("<H", value[offset:],2)[0];
    uint32_filesize = struct.unpack_from("<I", value[offset:],4)[0];
    dosdate_date    = struct.unpack_from("<H", value[offset:],8)[0];
    dostime_time    = struct.unpack_from("<H", value[offset:],10)[0];
    fileattr16_     = struct.unpack_from("<H", value[offset:],12)[0];
    offset += 12
    entry_name      = value[offset:(offset + (2 * uint32_filesize - 8))].decode('utf-16-le')
    offset += (2 * uint32_filesize - 4 )
    if offset % 2:
        offset += 1
    print( x, uint32_filesize, entry_name)

print( '\nThere is', (len(value) - offset), 'bytes left' )
```

**Output** (truncated): `.\SO\70039190.py`

```
0 44 ::{59031A47-3F72-44A7-89C5-5595FE6B30EE}
1 44 ::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}
2 44 ::{5399E694-6CE5-4D6C-8FCE-1D8870FDCBA0}
3 31 Software602 Form Filler.lnk
4 8 test
5 32 Virtual Russian Keyboard.lnk
…
49 22 WTerminalAdmin.lnk
50 22 AVG Secure VPN.lnk
51 44 ::{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}
52 29 powershell - Shortcut.lnk

There is 1176 bytes left
```

Honestly, I don't fully comprehend `offset` around `entry_name`…

### Edit

I have found (partial) structure for the rest of `value`. There are two tables containing row and column along with an index to `desktop_items` list for each desktop *icon*.

**Current row and column assignment is in the second table** (see the picture below). The first table supposedly contains default assignments for automatic *sort by* (from desktop context menu).

Unfortunately, I have no clue for interpretation of row and column values (e.g. `16256, 16384`) to *icon indexes* (3rd row, 2nd column).

```
import struct
import winreg
import pprint

aReg = winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
aKey = winreg.OpenKey(aReg,
          r"Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\1\Desktop",
          winreg.REG_BINARY)
name, value, type_ = winreg.EnumValue(aKey, 9)
aKey.Close()
aReg.Close()

offset = 0x10
head = [struct.unpack_from("<H", value[offset:],0)[0], # 2 bytes (word)
        struct.unpack_from("<H", value[offset:],2)[0],
        struct.unpack_from("<H", value[offset:],4)[0],
        struct.unpack_from("<H", value[offset:],6)[0],
        struct.unpack_from("<I", value[offset:],8)[0]  # 4 bytes (dword)
       ]
number_of_items = head[-1]
offset += 12
desktop_items = []
for x in range( number_of_items):
    uint16_size     = struct.unpack_from("<H", value[offset:],0)[0];
    uint16_flags    = struct.unpack_from("<H", value[offset:],2)[0];
    uint32_filesize = struct.unpack_from("<I", value[offset:],4)[0];
    dosdate_date    = struct.unpack_from("<H", value[offset:],8)[0];
    dostime_time    = struct.unpack_from("<H", value[offset:],10)[0];
    fileattr16_     = struct.unpack_from("<H", value[offset:],12)[0];
    offset += 12
    entry_name      = value[offset:(offset + (2 * uint32_filesize - 8))].decode('utf-16-le')
    offset += (2 * uint32_filesize - 4 )
    # uint16_size = location
    #        0x20 = %PUBLIC%\Desktop
    #        0x7c = %USERPROFILE%\Desktop
    desktop_items.append([x,
          '{:04x}'.format(uint16_size),
          0, 0,
          '{:04x}'.format(fileattr16_),
          entry_name])
    print('{:2}'.format(x),
          '{:04x}'.format(uint16_size),
          # '{:04x}'.format(uint16_flags), # always zero
          # '{:04x}'.format(dosdate_date), # always zero
          # '{:04x}'.format(dostime_time), # always zero
          '{:04x}'.format(fileattr16_),
          entry_name)

print( '\nThere is', (len(value) - offset), 'bytes left' )
print('head (12 bytes):', head)

offs = offset
head2 = []
for x in range( 32):
    head2.append(struct.unpack_from("<H", value[offs:],2*x)[0])

offs += 64
print( 'head2 (64 bytes):', head2)
for x in range( number_of_items):
    item_list = [
        struct.unpack_from("<H", value[offs:],0)[0],  # 0
        struct.unpack_from("<H", value[offs:],2)[0],  # column
        struct.unpack_from("<H", value[offs:],4)[0],  # 0
        struct.unpack_from("<H", value[offs:],6)[0],  # row 
        struct.unpack_from("<H", value[offs:],8)[0] ] # index to desktop_items
    # print( x, item_list)
    desktop_items[item_list[-1]][2] = int( item_list[1])
    desktop_items[item_list[-1]][3] = int( item_list[3])
    offs += 10

print(len(value), offset, offs, (offs - offset), '1st table, from start:')
table_1st = desktop_items
table_1st.sort(key=lambda k: (k[2], k[3]))
pprint.pprint(table_1st)
#pprint.pprint(desktop_items)

# 2nd table from behind
offs = len(value)
for x in range( number_of_items):
    offs -= 10 
    item_list = [
        struct.unpack_from("<H", value[offs:],0)[0],  # 0
        struct.unpack_from("<H", value[offs:],2)[0],  # column
        struct.unpack_from("<H", value[offs:],4)[0],  # 0
        struct.unpack_from("<H", value[offs:],6)[0],  # row 
        struct.unpack_from("<H", value[offs:],8)[0] ] # index to desktop_items
    # print(item_list)
    desktop_items[item_list[-1]][2] = int( item_list[1])
    desktop_items[item_list[-1]][3] = int( item_list[3])

print(len(value), offset, offs, (offs - offset), '2nd table, from behind:')
table_2nd = desktop_items
table_2nd.sort(key=lambda k: (k[2], k[3]))
pprint.pprint(table_2nd)
# pprint.pprint(desktop_items)
```

**Result** (an illustrative picture):

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer it semi-worked. I can see the files being listed by x and then if they are in the same column its listed by the row. My question is if there is any way to get the specific position of the icon (maybe something like (0, 0))?

Comment: @CozyCode Answer updated…

Answer (score 1):

it seems that you have an binary file that must be tranformed in floats, strings, etc.

Here you have a function that I have made that uses [struct unpack](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) to read an amount of bytes and then transform then in float or int or str, etc.

```
# Import
import numpy as np
import struct

def ReadBytes(file, fmt, size):
    """
    Function to read an amount of bytes and convert to the desired format.

    Parameters
    ----------
    file : Stream of file.
        Stream from open file.
         - `file = open("file.bin")`
    
    fmt : str
        String containing the format type of the object to be converted.
        - <https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html>
    
    size : int
        How many bytes should be read.

    Returns
    -------
    oc : object{int, float, str, ...}
        Desired object read from bytes and converted to desired type.

    """
    
    if size<0:
        # If you have an array you can use size = -n indicating that the array has n positions.
        # Length to be read.
        bs  = file.read(abs(size))
        # Converting length.
        size = struct.unpack('B',bs)[0]
        # Format considering the len.
        fmt = str(size)+fmt
          
    # Object to be read, in bytes.
    o = file.read(size)
    # Converting the object to the format desired.
    oc = struct.unpack(fmt, o)[0]
  
    return oc
```

In a simple usage, you can just use the struct unpack itself.
The following shows how to unpack 4 bytes to `int`:

```
struct.unpack('i', b'\x03\x01\x01\x01')

# Output-> (16843011,)
```

Comment: This might be a really simple question, but how exactly do I link a registry binary path to open() function.

Comment: @CozyCode, you can just put the path of the file ex:
`f = open('c:\user\Documents\file.bin', 'rb')` and then just use `ReadBytes(f, 'int', 4)` and after read all the things that you needed you do `f.close()`

Comment: But the IconLayouts reg_binary file is not in the usual c:\... To access it manually you have to use the registry editor tool. When I add the registry path to the open function it says something like: That directory doesn't exist.

Comment: @CozyCode Can you copy this file to another place that you have sure where it is just for a test?